# apache redirect misses /

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, hetzner

I configured port 80 with:

```
Redirect permanent / https://www.scool.cool/
```

but if I enter for example: `scool.cool/wp` I got `https://www.scool.coolwp`.

How can I fix this? How can I add the miss slash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in .htaccess or httpd.conf:

This will enable the Rewrite capabilities:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
```

This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Full example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

I hope to this help.

Comment: does the URL then contain also `www.`?